# How can I use CoreWCF in a .NET 6 web api?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm upgrading a .NET app to .NET 6. In it has a WCF Service in the application. I heard of that with CoreWCF it should be possible to port existing WCF services to .NET 6 (.net core).
But know that I'm looking the version is 0.4 and read somewhere that it's not production ready.
I would like to keep it the same way as before with the WCF Service be part of the Web API. Is it possible?
If it's possible any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about client or server? CoreWCF only works as client and not server, your server still needs to be run on .net framework.

Comment: My information may be wrong, I thought you were talking about this: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf - but I also found this: https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF - I only know the first, the "official" .net (core) port

Comment: @RandRandom ok, I would like to have an existing wcf-service in a web api, but now converted to .net 6 (.net core). Is it possible? Not consuming (client), but as a server in the same application.

Comment: @RandRandom https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/why-migrate-wcf-to-dotnet-grpc?view=aspnetcore-6.0 - looks like it's not supported. "CoreWCF is a community effort to bring support for hosting WCF services to .NET Core and .NET 5. A preview release is available and the project is working towards being production ready. CoreWCF only supports a subset of WCF's features, and .NET Framework apps that migrate to use it will need code changes and testing to be successful. CoreWCF is a good choice if an app has to maintain compatibility with existing clients that call WCF services."

Comment: You can check [alternatives to wcf](https://visualrecode.com/blog/wcf-alternatives-for-net5/) and [their changes in .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#windows-communication-foundation).